# alerting missing metric for many hosts in alertmanager

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have many servers that monitors with Prometheus, every host has the same metrics.

I need an alert rule that alerts when specific metric(such as `some_metrics`) missing on specific host after 5m.

I checked `absent` and `absent_over_time` but these functions do not return the labels of missing metric such as `ip` or `hostname`.

Also I should state that I don't want to create a rule for each host.

I have searched about it but I don't find any solution.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 4):

In order to get the labels, you need a metric which has all the labels you want. Usually, a good choice is `up` which also distinguish between a missing metric and an unreachable target.

The rule will alert if up (on a job) is 1 and the `UNLESS` binary operator will disable the alert if the metric is present on the instance:

```
- alert: MissingMetricInFooTarget
  rule: up{job="foo"} == 1 UNLESS ON(instance) some_metrics{job="foo"}
```

Comment: I think the question is how to do it if you have many jobs (or hosts in the original question) e.g. Find a missing job out of a 1000

Comment: I could answer with `rule: count(job) != 1000` :-).  Of course, it depends on your service discovery; at some point you must have a way to know something should exist or a metric should repect a given criteria. If you are in this case, it may also mean you are over-engineering your monitoring - you should firsrt monitor the result rather than the process; that's what robust monitoring is about.

Comment: Not disagreeing with larger points, but back to PromQL: I think I'd want a query to look  at the previous period, say yesterday, and then at today, and find all timeseries that are missing today vs yesterday, and vice versa. Didnt try it, but could be possible with PromQL

Comment: That's supposing your jobs run daily. What about weekend or holidays. That can quickly becomes tricky.

Comment: correct, this assumes your job runs daily. Otherwise look at [7d], etc. It's not perfect, but I cant think of anything else, PromQL-wise.  Probably joining two periods using group_left/right could produce the diff

Comment: Monitoring batch jobs is hard - especially as you pointed out when we want to detect that something is missing. In my paid job, we developed a small exporter, with our inventory as a backend, that exposes "info" metrics. We used them to write rules for expectations that we could not translate into terms of service discovery.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using something like the following promql query:

```
(some_metric offset 5m) unless some_metric
```

It will return `some_metric` metrics with all their labels, which had a value 5 minutes ago, but have no new values now.

This query uses the following PromQL features:

- [offset modifier](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier) for querying the data from the past
- [unless operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) for returning only time series, which have been disappeared during the last 5 minutes

P.S. the query can be simplified to `lag(some_metric[1h]) > 5m` when using VictoriaMetrics - an alternative Prometheus-like monitoring system I work on. See [docs for lag() function](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#lag).