# How can I find missing metrics in Prometheus that have a certain label?

Tags: prometheus

I have the following expression for an alert in Prometheus:

```
absent_over_time(node_filesystem_size_bytes{device=~"/dev/nvme.*"}[5m]) > 0
```

As far as I can tell, this will be > 0 if there are no metrics for /dev/nvme* in the last 5 minutes.

However, I would like this to take into account the `instance` that it runs on. That is, I want this to be triggered if **any instance** (preferably with a label saying which one(s)) is missing this metric over the last 5 minutes. I'm assuming that if one node is successfully scraped, this condition won't be true anymore.

There is an `instance` label on the `node_filesystem_size_bytes` metric, but if that metric is missing, I'm not sure how it could detect that.

Do I need to somehow get a list of `instance`s at the current time and join it with `node_filesystem_size_bytes` to accomplish this? Or is there some other way?

This is using node-exporter and the kube-prometheus-stack in a Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: I think I read that many-to-many relationships are not allowed. If I query for nodes (say there are 3), then try to join on these metrics (maybe there's 2 for any given node), I imagine this would create a many-to-many relationship. But I know very little about joins in promql, so not sure if that even makes sense. (also node==instance)

Comment: Actually I think it's answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62138933/2457821

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
(node_filesystem_size_bytes{device=~"/dev/nvme.*"} offset 5m)
  unless
node_filesystem_size_bytes{device=~"/dev/nvme.*"}
```

It should return time series matching the `node_filesystem_size_bytes{device=~"/dev/nvme.*"}` with all their labels, which had raw samples 5 minutes ago, but have no new samples aftewards.

Note that this query can be simplified to the following one when using VictoriaMetrics - Prometheus-like system I work on:

```
lag(node_filesystem_size_bytes{device=~"/dev/nvme.*"}[10m]) > 5m
```

It uses the [lag() function](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#lag), which returns the duration since the last raw sample per every input time series.

Comment: valyala : This question is about Promethus, not VictoriaMetrics. If you wan't to promote your software, at least add some disclamer

Comment: The answer contains the disclaimer that I work on VictoriaMetrics. It also contains Prometheus-specific solution for the original question